# Nul/Nulle equals no?

Tags: grammaire

Well, I've been learning French these days. And I am a little bit confusing about the usage of ***Nul/Nulle***.
I suppose the word ***Nul/Nulle*** means No. 
But I see some phrases like:

> Je n'ai nulle intention de vous déranger.

which means I don't have any intention to disturb you.
But why not ***J'ai nulle ..***.

I think it should be I have no .. instead of I don't have no.

So I don't know whether the phrase has something wrong. Could anyone help explain?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "Nulle" is a synonym of "aucune". For example "je n'ai aucune intention de vous déranger". Regarding "J'ai nulle" vs "Je n'ai nulle", I've always heard "Je n'ai nulle intention de ..."

Comment: Regarding "J'ai nulle" vs "Je n'ai nulle", it's mandatory to keep the "n'" in the sentence. The same goes for other sentence like "Je n'ai pas faim" that some people will transform into "J'ai pas faim", even if you can hear it from time to time (especially for children), it's grammatically incorrect as explained here : https://bescherelle.ca/emploi-de-la-negation/

Comment: @Ben *J'ai pas faim* is very idiomatic and is by large what native people would say. Don't confuse language registers and correctness. *J'ai nulle faim* is not idiomatic because *nulle* is very formal so it doesn't mix with the informal drop of *ne*.

Comment: @Ben, thank you for helping me with this question. I think now I can make out how to use these words. And as jlliagre mentioned, grammatically "ne .. pas" is correct, and we should write in this way, but orally sometimes It's okay to neglect the "ne" especially in informal conversations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And @jlliagre, thanks as well. Btw, as French is my third language, so I always translate it into English as I think they should be logically corresponded. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jlliagre I'm a native french speaker and agree that many people will say "J'ai pas faim". Nonetheless, according the the link I posted, it's a grammatical error. Bescherelle is kind of reference for french language and is used in almost all schools, that's why I think it's interesting to note they consider it a grammatical error. Of course it's used quite often, but it doesn't make it correct. To give a counter example, "quand est-ce qu'on bouffe" vs "quand est-ce qu'on mange", in this case they are both correct from a grammar point of view, but the first one is from a very familiar register.

Comment: This is confirmed by the Académie Française here : https://www.academie-francaise.fr/hesitez-pas-utiliser-une-negation-complete

Comment: @Ben Rien d'étonnant à ce qu'une grammaire prescriptiviste ou l'Académie qui ne l'est pas moins désapprouvent cette omission. Il n'en reste pas moins qu'il s'agit d'un fait de langue apparu dès le XVe siècle, et qui est généralisé en français **parlé** aujourd'hui. La grammaire du français écrit ne s'impose pas au français parlé. Un grand académicien l'omet d'ailleurs dans cette phrase: *Personne ne savait rien de ce grammairien un peu louche, **qui semblait surgit de nulle part**.*, Jean d'Ormesson.

Comment: @jlliagre on est d'accord sur le fond, c'est une expression courante en langage parlé, et par exemple Grévisse confirme cet usage. Attention cependant dans l'exemple ci-dessus il faut écrire "surgi" et non "surgit".

Comment: Si je peux me permettre une dernière remarque, dans l'exemple "qui semblait surgi de nulle part" on peut aussi se demander si c'est réellement une tournure négative. A mon sens "Il a surgi de nulle part" est correct car finalement il a surgi. Si c'est une tournure positive il n'y a pas besoin de "ne". 
A l'opposé par exemple de "Il ne se trouvait nulle part" où le "ne" est requis, même si à l'oral il sera souvent omis.

Comment: @Ben Oui, *surgi*, bien sûr. On ne peut pas corriger les commentaires, grrrr... L'exemple de d'Ormesson est extrait du bon usage. Grevisse est un observateur affuté de la langue, et indique qu'il s'agit d'une tendance de la langue courante, ce que n'infirme pas [ce NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+vient+de+nulle+part&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3)